# what parameter in username = request.data.get('username', '0')

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, request

A django rest framework tutorial,has a expression like this:

```
  username = request.data.get('username', '0')
```

My question is what dose the parameter '0' mean in this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will get and value if exists or return '0' if key not exists. 
[Description](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get)

Answer (score 1):

`request.data` is an dictionary, so the `get` function will work exactly the same on python dictionaries:

> get(key[, default])
>   Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)